# How to resolve CLI connection problem from java client to Jenkins server?

Tags: authentication, jenkins, command-line-interface

Connecting with CLI in default way towards new Jenkins instance hangs.

java -jar $JENKINS_HOME/war/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://git-dapp902.XXXXXXXX:17801 -auth admin:aaaaaaa  who-am-i
(aaaaaa = initial password for admin account)

Following actions were performed
- startup new Jenkins instance
- log on as admin with initial password
- enable global security JLNP on fixed port (without this, I would get a Connection Refused)
- restart the jenkins server
- launch the above java command (on the same Linux VM)
- client does not return. No logging on Jenkins server
- When client is canceled below logging is shown

```
java -jar $JENKINS_HOME/war/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://git-dapp902.XXXXXXXX:17801 -auth admin:aaaaaaa  who-am-i


WARNING: Connection #4 failed
java.io.EOFException
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readFully    (DataInputStream.java:202)
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:614)
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:569)
        at hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener$ConnectionHandler.run(TcpSlaveAgentListener.java:254)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found the solution.
The Jenkins URL does not need to point to the port in JLNP setting, but to the "plain" port.
Luc